# Python if statement, cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' object

Tags: python, if-statement, xml-parsing

My question is I want to check a variable in a xml variable called `xmlauthor` and I want to check if there is just basically something written on it. How should I do it?
This is what I have written so far:

```
for num in ic : 
    xmlauthor = dom.getElementsByTagName("author")[0]

    if not xmlauthor: 
        content += "***Changes by:"  + xmlauthor + "*** \n \n"
    else:
        content += "***Changes are made Anonumously** \n \n"
```

And here is the error I am getting on my console

```
content += "***Changes by:"  + xmlauthor + "*** \n\n" 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of a line there. Is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry lol forgot to add that in there.

Comment: It also seems like you have your logic backwards.  shouldn't it be `if xmlauthor` instead of `if not xmlauthor`?

Comment: I tried that as well and it still gives me that error.But you are right if xmlauthor is the better way, and is the way i have it now.

Comment: Is the if statement supposed to be inside the for loop?  To solve the error, try changing xmlauthor to str(xmlauthor)

Comment: I don't know what the type is that is returned by `dom.getElementsByTagName`, but you could also try `str(xmlauthor)` -- See if that works.

Comment: It is suppose to be inside a loop yes. How would i change xmlauthor into a str?

Comment: See my answer. But you probably want the *contents* of the tag, rather than the full tag (<>'s and all), right? What does your xml "author" tag look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using [xml.dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html): the `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return a list of strings, it returns a list of [Element](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#dom-element-objects) objects, so you can't concatenate `xmlauthor` to a string in the line

```
    content += "***Changes by:"  + xmlauthor + "*** \n \n"
```

You could convert it to a string by changing it to:

```
    content += "***Changes by:"  + xmlauthor.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "*** \n \n"
```

Comment: Well that does stop the error but instead of giving me the author or the item inside the <author> </author> tag it gives me this instead. 

<DOM Element: author at 0x2354260>

Comment: @GilbertLeeVera: You want the contents of the node. What does the node look like in your XML document?

Comment: Probably wind up needing something like `xmlauthor.childNodes[0].nodeValue`.

Comment: Kinda like this 
<log>
<logentry
   revision="33185">
<author>glv</author>
<date>2012-08-06T21:01:52.494219Z</date>
<paths>
<path
   kind="dir"
   action="M">/branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch</path>
</paths>
<msg>PATCH_BRANCH:N/A
BUG_NUMBER:N/A
FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A
OVERVIEW:N/A
Test 
</msg>
</logentry>
</log>

Answer (score 3):

A few tips for the next time:

- When you have an error like `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance'`, you could start by checking where the error happens. Where are you adding something to a string?
- Once you have identified where the problem is (the traceback gives you the line number anyway), you may want to check the type of the object you're trying to add to a string (in your example, it was `xmlauthor`. A `print type(xmlauthor)` should give you plenty of information.
- In particular, it may give you some idea of what the object is. In your example, we can assume it's some object defined in the `xml.dom` module. What does the documentation say about that? You can go and check the [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org), or you could try a `help(your_object)`.
- Is it the object you were expecting? Probably not. Is there something more interesting, like, a method or an attribute of this object that would solve your problem? Once again, go and check the doc, or just try a `dir(your_object)` to find what it can offer.
- Maybe it wasn't what you needed afterall, or you can't make sense of the doc. It's then a good idea to ask on SO. But only then.

Having a direct answer is great, of course, but understanding what went wrong is better, you will agree.

Comment: I agree knowing is half the battle. :)